# I can't track the random badge

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges

I am the all time top answerer in [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) (89 points on 11 answers).  I keep looking forward to getting a tag badge in it.

I can track C, version-control, database, math, git, history, open-source, and a whole host of other badges.

> [image]

Yet, when I filter to 'ran', I don't see it.  Typing in 'random' comes up completely blank.

> [image]

So, yea.  No random badge tracking for me. Even specific random tag badges.  Please fix.  I'd really like to track my progress on the random tag badge.

Comment: The [random] tag [is not eligible to have tag badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/13) at the moment, which is why it doesn't show up.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young ahh.  So, we need another dozen random questions.

Comment: @MichaelT: That should be easy! Just pick the next dozen questions to show up on the homepage! Oh wait, wrong random....

Comment: @NathanTuggy unfortunately, the [recent random question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/299581/40980) wasn't that good.  Its tough to find *good* random questions about random.